# `react-map-gl` ERROR Module not found error [MAPBOX]

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@math.gl/web-mercator/dist/esm/web-mercator-viewport.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'gl-matrix/mat4' in 'D:\Projects\react-app\frontend\node_modules\@math.gl\web-mercator\dist\esm'+
```

I get this on the development status, I tried repeatedly to install and uninstall `npm i react-map-gl`. I also tried to create a new app but facing same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is basically one of the dependencies of react-map-gl which is called gl-matrix has upgraded to version 3.4.0 from 3.3.0. Probably because it is a minor upgrade some of its dependant libraries

```
    ├─┬ mapbox-gl@1.13.1
│ └── gl-matrix@3.3.0 
├─┬ react-map-gl@5.3.17
│ └─┬ viewport-mercator-project@7.0.4
│   └─┬ @math.gl/web-mercator@3.5.5
│     └── gl-matrix@3.3.0  deduped
└─┬ viewport-mercator-project@6.2.3
  └── gl-matrix@3.3.0
```

automatically tried to fetch latest minor version. I'm trying force-resolutions with npm both on docker as well.

You can check which version your packages are using with

```
- npm ls gl-matrix
```

then try

`- npm install --unsafe-perm` to force resolutions if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Berk it's work... love you bro

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in the end had to add `gl-matrix` as an explicit dependency:

```
npm install gl-matrix
```

Comment: Thanks, Dain it's work... you made my day

Answer (score 1):

```js
Installation
Using react-map-gl requires react >= 16.3.

npm install --save react-map-gl mapbox-gl
```